# Vue 2.0 + webpack use component from npm package

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js

I am trying to get a project using webpack and Vue 2.0 set up and ran into a little trouble using components from npm packages (like vue-parallax) in my project.

I installed the package and everything appears to be there, but I'm not understanding where that is linked in my project.

What I think I'm missing is the import statement for 'parallax' in the script tag, but obviously that's just an educated guess.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
    <hello></hello>
    <parallax src=require('../assets/logo.png')></parallax>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Hello from './components/Hello'
//import parallax  ?

export default {
  name: 'app',
  components: {
    Hello,
    parallax
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: it's probably placed under the node_modules directory, so you can import it from there - try this `import parallax from 'vue-parallax'`

Comment: Thanks, I think that was it.  It got me to a render error in vue-parallax so it appears to be finding the component now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

per Belmin Bedak's comment:

it's probably placed under the node_modules directory, so you can import it from there - try this

```
import parallax from 'vue-parallax'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
components: {"parallax": require("vue-parallax")}
```

Or import directly:

```
import parallax from 'vue-parallax'
```